# S4 method for Rcpp generated S4 class still seems to need .onLoad()

Tags: r, class, methods, rcpp, r-s4

I cannot find a way to add an S4 `show` method  to the exported S4 class without using `.onLoad`.  The [Rcpp gallery example](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/custom-printer-exposed-modules/) suggests "Rcpp_yourclassname" as the object name should be sufficient but in practise my package complains it cannot not find the class:

```
Loading RcppS4show
in method for ‘show’ with signature ‘"Rcpp_Num"’: no definition for class “Rcpp_Num”
```

One can easily reproduce this by using the Rcpp module package skeleton:

```
# R console:
Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton("RcppS4show", path = "/tmp", module = TRUE)
# In /tmp/RcppS4show edit the file:
#   R/zzz.R
# ... as described below.
setwd("/tmp/RcppS4show")
devtools::load_all()
```

Add this to the bottom of `R/zzz.R`:

```
setMethod("show", "Rcpp_Num", function(object) {
    writeLines(paste("Num(x, y) =", object$x, object$y))
})
```

I can workaround this by wrapping the `loadModule` and `setMethod` functions in `.onLoad`:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
    loadModule("NumEx", TRUE)

    setMethod("show", "Rcpp_Num", function(object) {
        writeLines(paste("Num(x, y) =", object$x, object$y))
    })
}
```

Now I can see my show method works:

```
# R console:
new(Num)
#> Num(x, y) = 0 0
```

However both the module skeleton documentation and the [Rcpp-modules vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-modules.pdf) explain that `.onLoad` has been deprecated in favor of using `loadModule()`.

Additionally, having to abuse `.onLoad()` causes `devtools::check()` to note that `writeLines()` from my `show` method is bad practise:

```
> checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE
  File ‘RcppS4show/R/zzz.R’:
    .onLoad calls:
      writeLines(paste("Num(x, y) =", object$x, object$y))

  Package startup functions should use ‘packageStartupMessage’ to
    generate messages.
  See section ‘Good practice’ in '?.onAttach'.
```

Is there any way to register S4 methods without using `.onLoad`?

Comment: "Further modifying" an existing Rcpp Module object is closer to what John Chambers once tried in 'Rcpp Classes'  -- see maybe [this example in the unit tests](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/tree/master/inst/unitTests/testRcppClass). Otherwise this appears to be a road less traveled.  I simply define my Modules all at once...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel thank you for the quick reply!  I don't really follow your comment; what you do mean by saying you define your "Modules all at once"?  Do you not use the `RCPP_MODULE` macro and instead define S4 methods in R files with `.Call()` to the C++ functions? At the minute the unit test you pointed to explicitly says in [test/classes.R](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/5cf50bcdfc2054a73972b705b5c710e93d54f78a/inst/unitTests/testRcppClass/tests/classes.R#L17) that C++ classes cannot be found unless they are extracted from a module in R/load.R (line 42)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but...

Why not just define the show method on the C++ side? (Perhaps this is what Dirk meant when he said "I simply define my Modules all at once").

After running

```
Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton("RcppS4show", path = "/tmp", module = TRUE)
```

to create the package, I edited `Num.cpp` to the following

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

class Num {                     // simple class with two private variables
public:                         // which have a getter/setter and getter
    Num() : x(0.0), y(0){} ;

    double getX() { return x ; }
    void setX(double value){ x = value ; }

    int getY() { return y ; }

    // Show method
    void show() { Rcpp::Rcout << "Num(x, y) = " << x << " " << y << "\n"; }

private:
    double x ;
    int y ;
};

RCPP_MODULE(NumEx){
    using namespace Rcpp ;

    class_<Num>( "Num" )

    .default_constructor()

    // read and write property
    .property( "x", &Num::getX, &Num::setX )

    // read-only property
    .property( "y", &Num::getY )

    // show method
    .method("show", &Num::show)

    ;

}
```

Then from R

```
setwd("/tmp/RcppS4show")
devtools::load_all()
new(Num)
# Num(x, y) = 0 0
devtools::check()
# Most of the output is omitted, but...
# Status: OK
# 
# R CMD check results
# 0 errors | 0 warnings | 0 notes
showMethods("show")
# Function: show (package methods)
# Some output omitted...
# object="Rcpp_Num"
# More output omitted...
```